# cannot run jhipster command after installing latest generator-jhipster

Tags: node.js, npm, jhipster

**Overview of the issue**

After installing jhipster using npm, when I try to run any jhipster command I get the following error.

**Motivation for or Use Case**

JHipster commands are not running

**Reproduce the error**

1. Install jhipster using npm as in docs `npm install -g generator-jhipster`
2. run `jhipster` or `jhipster info`
  3.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172
      throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
      ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\is-promise\index.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\is-promise\index.js from C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\run-async\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\is-promise\index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\is-promise\package.json.

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:13)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\run-async\index.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

**Versions**

```
npm 6.14.4
node v12.16.2
OS: win10
generator-jhipster@6.8.0
```

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11638

Comment: I installed node v12.0.0 and it works.

Comment: FWIW, this was caused by https://github.com/then/is-promise/issues/13.